# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1130] Host 'xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have set my local ip in database connection.

Like...

```
'db' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=192.168.0.104;dbname=adult_guide_directory',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ],
```

But, i have found one error...

[image]

Whats worng in my db connection?

Comment: Check DB permissions if it allows connections from your IP. `localhost` != `192.168.0.104`

Comment: you need to add a mysql user in your mysql server with any host `%` like `user@%` or  `user@host` like `root@bharat` rather than `root@localhost` if you are trying to connect remotely or from a docker container